# Adding custom tag buttons to jwysiwyg?

Tags: jquery, jwysiwyg

How can I add a button to jwysiwyg that will add an HTML tag to the selected text?  I tried this, based on the documentation:

```
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg({
    controls: {
       tt: { visible: true, tags: ['tt'], css: { class: 'tt', className: 'tt' } }
    }
})
```

... And it adds the button, all right, but then the button doesn't seem to actually *do* anything.  I select some text, click on it, and nothing happens.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a button and specify the 'exec' property, like so:

```
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg({
    controls: {
       tt: { 
             visible: true, 
             tags: ['tt'], 
             css: { class: 'tt', className: 'tt' }, 
             exec: function(){
                  //Do Something
                }
            }
    }
});
```

with $('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('setContent', '') you can clear the textarea.